# 'Not yet' or 'Never yet'

Tags: grammar, adverbs

What's the difference between usage of '*Not yet*' and '*Never yet*' in the following sentences..

I've *not yet* tasted it.

I've *never yet* tasted it.

And is the second sentence grammatically valid?

Answer (score 5):

*I've not yet tasted it* or *I've not tasted it yet* imply that you expect to do so quite soon. Probably someone has asked how you like a present of food or drink they recently gave you.

*I've never tasted it* means that you have not tried that kind of food in your entire life. *Never yet* is grammatically valid, but I think it would only be used when the speaker wants to be very emphatic.

> I've never yet lied about my age and I don't intend to start now!

Comment: I think the kind of context where ***never yet*** might occur as an ***emphatic*** usage is typified by [*They have **never yet** sustained such a defense*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22they+have+never+yet+sustained+such%22) as uttered in a courtroom context. Generally speaking, ***not yet*** strongly implies ***...but expected to happen at some time in the future*** (or even ***overdue***). But to my mind, that cited usage implies ***never have, and probably never will***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Emphatic, yes. "I've met many fools in my life, but I've never yet come across as great a booby as you", my mother might have said.

Comment: She would have said it affectionately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks a lot..